# Jeep Commander all wheel drive automatic transmission no Park

Tags: transmission, jeep, gears, torque-converter, commander

I have an '07 Jeep Commander (all wheel drive).  Coming home, I went across railroad tracks and lost all my gears.  No park, no gears.  The transmission fluid is full.

My mechanic says it's a bad transmission, but the Jeep dealer says it could be the torque converter. However, inside where the linkage locks it in park and engages gears there's no sound -- feels broken to me.  (Note that when I got the car back from the mechanic, he said he did check it out, but there's no sign of the transmission pan being off, so he may or may not have.)

There's no resistance at all switching the gear lever from park to low. I can't hear it do anything inside transmission (before you could hear it click into gear).  I've gotten under it and let my son-in-law move it back and forth -- no sound, no resistance. The shifter moves but no sound.

Comment: Did the mechanic and dealer actually examine the car?

Comment: Well he said he did but transmission  show's no sign of haveing pan off. Or anything else I can see .so I would have to say no

Comment: When you move the gear selector, it feels loose?

Comment: Easy as it can be from park to low no resistance at all. Can not hear it do nothing inside transmission . Have gotten under it and let my son-in-law move it back and forth no sound no resistance .the shifter moves but not one sound does it make . before you could bhear it click .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair, by the way!

Comment: When you say the shifter moves, do you mean the arm going into the transmission or just the linkage to the arm? And when you say "park to low no resistance" do you mean that it doesn't lock in park? Like you don't have to press the button to start moving it?

Comment: Does not lock in park you can go under the Jeep Commander  take linkage lose move shifter from park to low not a sound .back and forth like hooked to nothing. you can put it in park from the linkage at transmission  get out from under the it push it around.